# Java: Using .add(new Methodname()) to add a set of String values to each element in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am not sure if I have posted the questions correctly, but here is the problem. I am aware you can add a String or an int value to an element of an ArrayList. But I want to have each element be a set of Strings firstname, lastname, and a relation value (ideally). I don't know if this is asking too much for an ArrayList, but it would be ideal.

Here is the ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Member> family = new ArrayList<Member>(); 
    family.add(new Member());
    family.add(new Member());
    family.add(new Member());
    family.add(new Member());

    for(Member dad : family){
        dad.setFirstName("Father");
        dad.setLastName("Last");
     }

    for(Member mom : family){
        mom.setFirstName("Mother");
        mom.setLastName("Last");
    }

    for(Member son : family){
        son.setFirstName("Son");
        son.setLastName("Last");
    }

    for(Member daughter : family){
        daughter.setFirstName("Daughter");
        daughter.setLastName("Last");
    }
```

Member is a class for getting/setting these values, as well as an override for getting output on the console.

However, when I print to console I get a completely wrong answer. I get four times the last element Daughter, with four times each:

```
[Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last), Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last), Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last), Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last)]
[Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last), Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last), Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last), Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last)]
[Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last), Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last), Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last), Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last)]
[Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last), Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last), Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last), Member (firstname=Daughter, lastname=Last)]
```

What gives?

BTW, this is the what I am using to print:

```
    @Override
public String toString() {
    return "Member (firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ")";
}
```

Comment: Think about your `for` loops - how do they work? Is each loop looking at one item, or *every* item?

Comment: I noticed if I comment out the last three for loops, then the result is Father/Last. If I comment out the last three family.adds, the result is one [ Member (stuff) ]. Been thinking about those for loops. Seems not the correct way to give values to the method. I would say the for loop is not looking at every item but only Member daughter (or last for loop). I cannot add any arguments to the Member() method, unless I create a constructor in the Member class. Still pondering this.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every next `for` loop in your code is resetting the values updated in your `family` list by the previous one. that's why your list has only the values set by the last iteration.

Comment: Ah... I see. That explains the odd behaviour. Is it even possible to add an Object such as Member() to an ArrayList?